# connected to a wifi network but cant access internet

Tags: wifi, vmware-workstation, vmware-player

i think i have a unique problem here i don't for two days i have been searching regarding this issue.

I am using windows 8.1  i have installed VM player in it.
My problem is that i am connected to a WiFi network but i cant access internet. I am using USB WiFi router i use the same WiFi router in my desktop and it is working completely fine . While i use VM player the router is detected WiFi network is connected i can even login to the router and ping other devices connected to it. But i cant use internet with the WiFi . I  am using kali in VM so i thought it was the OS issue so i installed windows xp but the same issue continues . I am so desperate right now . Any help would be much appreciated.

NB: i also tried these steps with VMware workstation 12

*And thanks in advance.*

Configuration :

- Main PC OS : windows 8.1
- VMplayer : Kali and Windows XP.
- WIFI router : TPLINK 722N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even I was facing a similar issue. I tried to disable the rest of the networks except the one that is connected to [Network adapter settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NowJ7.jpg)the Internet such as VMnet1 and VMnet8 ( in my case ). Also do check that if you are connecting through NAT in your virtual machine. Hope it helps :)